# Common DebuggerDisplay attribute implementation

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, .net-core, debuggerdisplay

I'm trying to implement the common/general **DebuggerDisplay** attribute to avoid formatting it for every single usage which would simply show every property of the class. That's what I've achieved so far, my extension method looks like this

```
public static class DebuggerExtension
{
    public static string ToDebuggerString(this object @this)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var property in @this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property != null)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(@this, null)?.ToString();
                builder.Append($"{property.Name}: {value}, ");
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it like this and it basically works:

```
[DebuggerDisplay($"{{this.ToDebuggerString()}}")]
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any existing extension to generate the **DebuggerDisplay** string? The built in VS implementation just adds the method which returns ToString() which doesn't really help
2. Can I call the method on some compiler-checked way, not as a string? "this." is obviously  not available in the attribute arguments. Maybe any expression?
3. Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'ToDebuggerString()' again instead of 'ToString()' in extension method?
It may interest you. [Visual Studio's Natvis Debugging Framework Tutorial](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/natvis-tutorial/)
The example below may be helpful to you. (It may be missing!)

```cs
public static class DebuggerExtension
{
    public static string ToDebuggerDisplay(this object o)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(o, null))
            return "null";
        else if (o is string)
            return string.Format("\"{0}\"", (string)o);
        else if ((o is DateTime) || (o is TimeSpan))
            return string.Format("{{{0}}}", o);
        else if (o is System.Collections.ICollection)
            return string.Format("{{Count={0}}}", ((System.Collections.ICollection)o).Count);
        else if (o is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
        {
            int nCount = 0;
            System.Collections.IEnumerator e = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)o).GetEnumerator();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                nCount++;
            }
            return string.Format("{{Count={0}}}", nCount);
        }

        Type objType = o.GetType();

        if (objType.IsPrimitive || objType.IsEnum)
            return o.ToString();
        else if (objType.IsArray)
            return string.Format("{{Count={0}}}", ((Array)o).Length);

        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public
            | BindingFlags.GetProperty
            | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        string retVal = "{";
        int ndx = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (!pi.CanRead)
                continue;

            DebuggerBrowsableAttribute attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<DebuggerBrowsableAttribute>();
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(attr, null) && (attr.State == DebuggerBrowsableState.Never))
                continue;

            if (ndx++ > 0)
                retVal += " ";

            retVal += string.Format("{0}={1}", pi.Name, pi.GetValue(o).ToDebuggerDisplay());

            if (ndx > 2)
            {
                retVal += " ...";
                break;
            }
        }
        retVal += "}";

        return (ndx > 0) ? retVal : o.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### Uses

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay(@"{this.ToDebuggerDisplay(),nq}")]
```

Comment: can you show me the call please?

Comment: VladL: I'm sorry I did not understand! You can use "DebuggerTypeProxy" for each class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2022

Comment: [DebuggerDisplay(@"{this.ToDebuggerDisplay(),nq}")]

Comment: Well, that's basically what I'm doing now and trying to avoid but thanks

Comment: VladL: Sorry, I don't know of a solution other than this and using natvis.